# How to deal with web forms with lots of data?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, session, browser-cache

I am curious to know about the real-world solution for dealing with forms that have large amount of data/fields or a wizard like interface (may be using AngularJS kind of GUI framework), especially if we want to take care of a scenario where the data persistence on back-end fails.

My questions are:

1. Is the form data saved in session, in the interim, (or may be on Browser itself using the JS libraries) till the user saves the final "Save" button?
2. Or is the data saved each time (i.e. on the user traversing from one screen to another using "Previous" or "next" buttons) on to a back-end database?
3. What happens if the form data has to be sent to an external web-service (instead of a database) and the call fails (due to timeout or any error)? 
   There is a strong chance that we will lose all the user entered data (unless we save it in a local database and re-try the web-service call later).
4. Do any of the caching f/w have any role to play here (including any AngularJS caching f/w)?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: using `localstorage` may help you a lot. I don't have any idea about your work but I think saving the form each time in each state will cause complexity on your back-end. you may want to take some snapshots of your data at each step and put it in `localstorage`. about your third question you may want to put a middleware between client and database which that would put the form's data in a queue and then do the storing procedure at first, and you can think about using `localstorage` again to replay the request at last!

Comment: Thanks Sajjad. By `localstorage` do you mean https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp?

Comment: @dchcks exactly. there are `sessionstorage` and `localstorage`. `sessionstorage` is freed on browser refresh and won't remain but `localstorage` will